# Setting Excel NumberFormat for Dates ignoring the locale in native C++

Tags: c++, excel, com, native, office-automation

I'm using Excel COM automation from native C++. My goal is to set the NumberFormat of a range for dates. The Problem is, the format string Excel expects depends on the user's locale.

Example:
If the locale is english i have to set the NumberFormat to "dd.mm.yyyy"
If the locale is german i need to use "TT.MM.JJJJ" to get the same result.

I'v found a lot of solutions for .NET, unfortunately i don't have that luxury. The usual solution was to temporarily set the locale of the the Excel thread to english, but it doesn't seem possible with native C++.

I could read the default system locale and then hardcode different format strings, but this won't work as soon as someone uses a locale i haven't included explicitely, so this is a bad solution.

So, how do i solve this problem so it works no matter which locale is used?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use the system time formatter (like: _tcsftime, strftime, wcsftime) to format the date/time structure to the locale of the running system. Since both your program and excel is expected to run on the same PC, it should work properly without even knowing how the local date/time string look like.

As a fall-back solution, you may have to provide a series of hard-coded format string and/or a user-manually-entered string in the option-configuration section of your program, just in case the default locale format fails.

Additional informations after first reply comment from OP: --------------

locale setting affect the text-display presentation of a datetime-binary-object in the UI only. Such datetime-binary-object is alway stored as a binary structure in a very consistent way, irregardless of locale setting even in its each different contexts, be it in Excel (Date/Time format cell), C++ (various structure depends on api), VisualBasic (Variant).

So if your intention is to export the datetime binary structure to excel, not as a strng, you can alway use the "variant" type to store the date value as excel-automation uses the IDispatch interface. You can forget about the locale setting totally.

Adding of code fragment to export datetime variant and format the cell by code: ----------------

I am using MFC so the the code is very simple, you may have to convert to winapi youself

```
_Application app;
if (!app.CreateDispatch("Excel.Application"))
{   AfxMessageBox("Cannot start Excel !");
    return;
}
app.SetVisible(TRUE);   
COleVariant VOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);
Workbooks objbooks = app.GetWorkbooks();
_Workbook objbook = objbooks.Add(VOptional);
Worksheets objsheets = objbook.GetWorksheets();
_Worksheet objsheet = objsheets.GetItem(COleVariant((short)1));

// get current date time
COleDateTime timeCurrent = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();

// setting date values
Range range;
range = objsheet.GetRange(COleVariant("A2"), COleVariant("B3"));
range.SetValue(COleVariant(timeCurrent));
//  range.SetNumberFormat(COleVariant("dd/mm/yyyy"));
range.SetNumberFormat(COleVariant("dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"));

AfxMessageBox("Done...");
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately both of them won't work. I need the date as a chart axis. To make the date-axis-options available (which is why i'm doing all this, so i can say excel to make a major tick and label the axis every month), simply passing the date as a string won't work, i need to use =DATEVALUE() and then format the cell as a date. Thus i need to use the Excel NumberFormat.

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to add a line break, but hitting enter sent the comment and it says i can't edit it. The second solution doesn't work either. Yes i can hardcode the number format depending on the locale (which is what i did now), but it's not a real solution. The program is about 20 years or so old and the settings are saved on the DB and thus are shared by all users at a customer. There is also an Ini file, but the program can be installed on a network drive and thus the ini file can be shared too. But the local can be different for each user of course.

Comment: Passing the date as variant of type date solves the problem for me, thanks a lot. Unfortunately this isn't a general solution, since this way you can only display the date in standard format. If someone needs to format it differently, this won't help either. As an example: if you want it as "Wednesday, February 27, 2013", which corresponds to the excel number format string "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"

Comment: @Naryoril - You can also format the cell in your export code using range.SetNumberFormat, please refer to my added code fragment.

Comment: yes, that's exactly the way i'm doing it. But if you set your windows locale to German, French or Italian, the SetNumberFormat will throw an exception, because in case of German Excel expects the NumberFormat as "TTTT, MMMM TT, JJJJ" in this case (day = Tag = T, month = Monat = M, year = Jahr = J). In .NET you can set the thread locale of the excel thread to english and just use the english format, but i couldn't find a way to do that (or something with the same effect) in native C++/MFC